# How do I fix CTA buttons on my Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, button

So I have CTA buttons on my Wordpress site that were functioning a couple months ago, but now they are no longer working. I know the basics of HTML and such but not this level.

https://www.hsisensing.com/research-development/

Learn More

Answer (score 0):

after checking your website, seems like div class named: title-hover, covering up your cta buttons, if you build your site through template builder, consider switch to something called 'wireframe' mode, so you can review your missused element

Comment: I've found what you're talking about in the theme editor. What would be the best way to fix this without a builder? It's a complete custom theme so no template builder was used as far as I know.

Comment: use wordpress theme editor, find the file or template file that correspond to the page that have issues, edit that dirrectly on wordpress theme editor